# Load CSV and convert to date

Tags: r

I've imported array from csv with data %d.%m.%Y but R reads as %Y.%m.%d. Which function should I use? Here are some my attempts but not succesfull

```
x <- c$Date
fast_strptime(x, format = "%d.%m.%Y")

parse_date(x, format = "%d.%m.%Y")

 cols(
    x = col_date(format = "%d.%m.%Y")
  )
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

To change the format of Date r uses `asDate` just like `asType` is used :-

```
x<- as.Date(dates,
  format = "%m/%d/%y")
```